# Как запретить поворот экрана?

Tags: браузер, android, javascript, html, iphone

Есть сайт для мобильных устройств. Требуется как-то запретить поворот экрана чтобы всегда ориентация была только Portrait.

Answer (score 6):

Полностью запретить поворот нативного обозревателя для Android (и думаю для iPhone также) нельзя, но можно отследить сам факт поворота и применить нужные стили так, чтобы страница выглядела желаемым образом. Для этого нужно слушать событие onorientationchange и проверять свойство window.orientation. Примерно так:

```
window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    var orientation = Math.abs(window.orientation) == 90 ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';
    // Применяем нужные нам стили
}, false);
```